# Hide div when height is greater than certain amount of pixel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple question, can I hide a `div` when height is greater than, for example, `1000px`?

If the `div` is smaller than this height, we can see the content inside it.

Comment: Do you mean "when the height is greater than 1000px"?

Comment: Do you mean if the viewport height is greater than 1000px or if the contents of the DIV are greater than 1000px?

Comment: the content of the div  ;)

Comment: One major question: What is the factor of the div being resized?

Comment: it's okay @Nooneknows Tarini found a solution ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbmbVL

You have 2 divs, a tall one and a small one.
Inside JS you have a global variable, named maxHeight.

On document ready, I hide all the `data-hide-based-height` div with a height that is over than maxHeight.

PS if you try to change maxHeight, for example to 150, you should see both the divs

Comment: your example is great i work on it now to see if I can do something with it thank you !!!

Comment: Great! Please mark question as answered if you think it is